# Android as rubber ducky

Tags: usb, keyboard, shell

Watching Mr Robot I came across a small device called a rubber ducky. It simulates a keyboard and executes a given list of commands, like keystrokes and such.
Now that I am too cheap to buy a real one and none of my USB sticks are capable of having their bootloader reflashed to turn them into one, I thought, since you could use your android as a USB keyboard, wouldn't it be possible to use it as a rubber ducky as well?
I have tried the droidducky script (http://zx.rs/6/DroidDucky---Can-an-Android-quack-like-a-duck/), but without luck...

Are there any alternatives?

- rocket_doge_

Answer (score 3):

Using an Android device as a rubber ducky is possible, but setting it up can be difficult. Your device most likely doesn't work with the payload because it is not rooted and/or doesn't support HID keyboard output at kernel level. If there is no support for HID, this can be fixed by flashing a kernel which does support this, however the number of supported devices isn't exactly huge, meaning you would have to edit, compile and flash the kernel by yourself.

You can see the exact procedure here: https://github.com/plowsec/android-ducky

Here is a list of devices which already have compiled kernels (it is accessible from the first one, though): https://github.com/pelya/android-keyboard-gadget

Comment: it's 2 years later, any updates?